# Compare class's field with it's name

Tags: c#, .net

I whould like to have a Dictionary, where value is field of type myClass, and key is this field's name. I tried FieldInfo:

```
actions = new Dictionary<string, myClass> ();
FieldInfo[] fields = triggerScript.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
int iterator = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++) 
{
    var field = fields[i];
    if (field.FieldType == typeof(myClass))
    {
        actions.Add (fields[i].Name, fields[i].GetValueDirect());
    }
}
```

But FieldInfo doesn't contains reference to the field it discribes. How can I do this?

---

### Example:

```
public SimpleAction OnClick;
```

In Dictionary:

> key - `OnClick`;
>
> value - `(SimpleAction)OnClick`;

### UPDATE

I have an assigned object of tyte SimpleAction, and whant to store it's reference and name in dictionary.

Comment: By the way, in your example, maybe a member `OnClick` of type `SimpleAction` should be an **event** and not a field? I know it's not related to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ToDictionary` method from LINQ for simpler. Also, to get the value of Field, use method [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx):

```
var actions = triggerScript.GetType()
           .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
           .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof (SimpleAction))
           .ToDictionary(field => field.Name, 
                         field => (SimpleAction)field.GetValue(triggerScript));
```

Comment: Yes, this explains how to cope with the fact that the `FieldInfo` object doesn't have a reference to any particular instance on which the field "sits". Therefore, you use `.GetValue(instance)`.

Comment: But how can I get currect instance for current `FieldInfo`?

Comment: @SentineL: I am not sure I understand correctly, but you know the current object you need to get value of FieldInfo, right? If not, could you elaborate more your question

Comment: Yes, I have an assigned object of tyte `SimpleAction`, and whant to store it's reference and name in dictionarry.

Comment: @SentineL: Okay, what's wrong with my current answer? Could you update your question for more clear?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand you currect... Via code in answer, I will get an array of `FieldInfo`, somehow sorted. I can get names of that fields, also values themselves, using method `FieldInfo.GetValue`, but what parameter showld I give to `GetValue` method? Instance of what?

Comment: @SentineL: Should be instance of object which contains Field, in your case: `triggerScript` is an instance, right?